# multiple color detection by using a hsv image

Tags: opencv

I want to detect red black and blue colors. In a video.. Can I use region of interest for this? When I use `inrange` function I can only detect one color. What I want is to detect if any one of the three colors are there in a particular region of the image. Can I use the same hsv image for this? For my project I have to detect these three colors and sort them using a hardware mechanism. I'm new to opencv. Can you please tell me how to detect these colours using it? It would be a great help if you can give me an algorithm to detect these 3 colours.

Comment: use inRange 3 times?

Comment: Too many questions, it's difficult to understand what's your problem and what are your difficulties exactly... You say `inrange` is giving unsatisfactory results, try to explain better, maybe show some images.

Comment: what i'm gonna make is a lego sorting machine.i just wanna identify the colors of the lego coming along the convey belt.and i just wanna put them in to different bins according to the color.. something similar to this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wCPk3Wz4EkI